# Disabling the dialogs shown when opening an application for the first time on OSX

Tags: python, macos, info.plist, osx-gatekeeper, launch-services

I am making an app on osx 10.9 using python 2.7.
But when it is launched first time, warning comes.

### You are opening the application MYAPP for the first time. Are you sure you want to open this application?

```
The application is in a folder named Applications. To see the application in the Finder without opening it, click Show Application.
```

So, how to avoid this warning. Does I need to make some changes in **info.plist of app**.

I had gone through this [Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/266176/disabling-the-dialogs-shown-when-opening-an-application-for-the-first-time) but nothing is mentioned about app side changes.

I **don't want user** to use any sort of command to run or do changes manually.
User can disable by `"com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO"` for all or `"xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine Application.app"` for particular app.

I had also **signed** the app with developer ID.

So, how to disable this dialog box from popping.